# Default jQuery fade animation method not using the default fx queue?

Tags: jquery, animation, queue

I've wrote my first jQuery script that animate multiple "wall" of images with a HTML like this:

```
<div id="home-wall">
    <div class="wall" animation-order="default">
        <div class="uk-grid grid uk-grid-preserve wk-gallery wk-gallery-wall zoom">
            <a class="" href=""><img src="gallery/zoom/image1.jpg"></a>
            <a class="" href=""><img src="gallery/zoom/image2.jpg"></a>
            <a class="" href=""><img src="gallery/zoom/image3.jpg"></a>
            <a class="" href=""><img src="gallery/zoom/image4.jpg"></a>
            <a class="" href=""><img src="gallery/zoom/image5.jpg"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wall" animation-order="default">
    ....
    </div>
</div>
```

Still I don't get why when I use a call like this (in the script or directly in the Firebug console)

```
jQuery(".wall").first().fadeOut(400).next().fadeIn(400);
```

the fade animation doesn't seems to queue in the default `fx` queue [like the docs says](http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue2), but happen simultaneously. I'm expecting to first see the fade out of the first wall and only when it's completely hid (`display:none`) seeing the next wall fade in.

What I didn't understand? Have I to create a a custom animation queue?

Comment: have you tried using `setTimeout()`?

Comment: @SAMTHEMAN999 Thanks, it'd be a solution but I want to understand why it doesn't follow the default `fx` queue rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery animation queues are *per-element*, not *per-document*. You're fading in a different element to the one that was faded out, so the animations can happen simultaneously.

For simple two-element cases like this, the easiest way to make animation sequential is to use the [animation function's `complete` callback](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/). The callback function will run when the first animation finishes, giving you the effect you're after. Like this:

```
$('.wall').first().fadeOut(400, function() {
    $(this).next().fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: That's what I was missing! From the docs it seems that ALL the animations are queued in `fx`... or I completely missed this topic?

Comment: Each element has one queue called `fx`. [The documentation you linked](http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue2) does talk about the per-element nature, but it's not really drawing attention to it. Here's some emphasis added: "**Every element** can have one to many queues of functions attached to it by jQuery... Queues allow a sequence of actions to be called on **an element** asynchronously, without halting program execution. The typical example of this is calling multiple animation methods on **an element**."